# What symptoms on Langara is Jonas referring to?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In S06E13, upon returning from a mission with an alien device, Jonas Quinn sees an alien creature that no one else can see. When the entire team is ordered to take some down-time, they discuss the situation and Jonas says the following:

> JONAS: You think I'm having symptoms related to my prior exposure to naquadria, like the others on my planet.

Other than S05E21, in which Daniel Jackson received

> a lethal dose of radiation poisoning from his exposure to the Naquadria device

I'm not aware of any "symptoms" related to Naquadria exposure.

**What symptoms on Langara is Jonas Quinn referring to?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He's referring to the events of the Season 6 episode 7 "[Shadow Play](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0709169/?ref_=ttep_ep7)", in which three of the fellow scientists who worked with him (Dr. Kieran, Jonas' former professor, also being one of the main antagonists of this story) end up with a form of Naquadria poisoning from frequent exposure. The effects of the Naquadria poisoning cause a schizophrenic-type lesion in the brain that results in hallucinations and full on delusions - like one might think apply to seeing alien creatures that nobody else can.

Comment: Somehow I missed that episode - I'll go back and watch it. Thank you!